# Can we call a Rest API method and retrieve more than 50,000 records in a Salesforce Environment?

Tags: soql, rest-api

I'm not sure how to phrase this question correctly, but the gist is that, an external party will access our Salesforce environment via REST Api and retrieve more than 50,000 account records.

Now I know we can only query 50,000 records via SOQL and that we need to do pagination to get more. However, we're not developing a UI, we just want to retrieve account records in the Salesforce environment and we expect the return would be more than 50,000 records.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: BTW, if you are implementing your own custom REST API using Apex then you will be limited to 50000 records.

Comment: If this is a one-off request, or if it'll happen infrequently, you may want to consider using Data Loader instead.

Answer (score 1):

The 50000 limit is not relevant for the Rest API.

You will get up to 2000 records in 1 call, if the query have more records then you will get value in the result 'nextRecordsUrl' that should be used to get the next part.

See link:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000332074&type=1&mode=1
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_query.htm